# JQuery, AJAX, JSON: calling on separate files

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm embarrassed to ask this because I'm sure the answer must be simple. I'm playing with some very basic AJAX stuff, trying to learn how to use data from a JSON file to populate an HTML page.

Here is the JSON file:

```
{"animals": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "chicken"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "cow"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "sheep"
  }
]}
```

And my HTML file, calling JQuery and containing my JQuery file inside:

```
<body> <!-- nothing called in the head -->

  <h1>Why Aren't You Working?</h1>

  <select id="people"></select>

  <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javaScript">
    var $select = $('#people');

    $.getJSON( "example.JSON", function(data){
      $select.html('');
      $.each(data.person, function(key, val){ 
        $select.append('<option id="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
      })
    });     
  </script>
</body>
```

This works fine. But when I take my JS code out of this html.page and call a separate JS file (without the code modified at all) the JS doesn't work and the JSON data doesn't populate the page.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm guessing there's an easy fix?

Thanks!

UPDATE: This is the HTML with the JS removed and the JS file beneath it. HTML file, JS file, and JSON file are all in the same folder. No errors reported on the console. Thanks for responding so far!

index.html

```
<body>
  <h1>Why Aren't You Working?</h1>
    <select id="people"></select>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javaScript" src="example.js"></script>
</body>
```

example.js

```
var $select = $('#people');

$.getJSON( "example.JSON", function(data){
  $select.html('');
  $.each(data.person, function(key, val){ 
    $select.append('<option id="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
  })
});
```

Comment: `$.getJSON( "example.JSON", function(data){` be sure the path to your json-file is correct and to include your external js-file in the html-file

Comment: Does your console show any errors?

Comment: You probably need to wrap your code in `$(function () { ... });` or `$(document).ready(function { ... });`.

Comment: Your code should work just fine. Read your console for more information, i expect it to be complaining about CORS due to running on the local file system rather than a webserver, or an incorrect url path.

Comment: @KevinB Okay. You are apparently better at mindreading than I....

Comment: is your js and json file same folder?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan look at the code, the select is before teh code, therefore it will exist before the code runs.

Comment: @empiric i simply gave a few ways that this code in particular could fail. As written, it should work on a webserver, and it would fail on the local file system.

Comment: @KevinB and you're assuming he's placing that same code, *now in an external file*, in the same place.

Comment: @KevinB Just because we have different assumptions, doesn't make either of us wrong.

Comment: Thanks all. I've updated the above to show my HTML and code as separate files. Everything is in the same folder and there are no errors reported by the console.

Comment: yeah, both cases should work just fine, with and without document ready handler. F12, inspect console.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this on plunker and its working fine. You can download the working code from it. The only suspecious thing in your JS was use of data.person, while it should be data.animals as per your example.JSON

HTML:

```
<body>
  <h1>Why Aren't You Working?</h1>
  <select id="people"></select>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javaScript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
  var $select = $('#people');

  $.getJSON("example.JSON", function(data){
    $select.html('');
    $.each(data.animals, function(key, val){ 
      $select.append('<option id="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
    })
  });   
});
```

example.JSON :

```
{
  "animals":[
   {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "chicken"
   },
   {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "cow"
   },
   {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "sheep"
   }
 ]
}
```

Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/kNAZMNJsZY6X3ol7GTDG?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for checking this. I still don't understand (and apologies because I'm still learning) why this would run on Plunker but not locally?

Answer (score -3):

I can't tell without seeing your code with the removed js, but you probably have the external js file before you import the jquery file.

Comment: *"I can't tell without seeing your code with the removed js"* then don't answer.

Comment: HTML with removed JS added to the original question. Thanks!